# Get view child from simple class

Tags: android

Can I somehow get child of a View from a class other than an Adapter or one that extends Activity?

```
ImageView v = (ImageView)parent.getChildAt(position);
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.test2);
```

I need to change each ImageViews in my GridView as they are dynamically downloaded.

My getView:

```
       @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        if (DefinedValues.width/3 < DefinedValues.height/4)
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams
                (DefinedValues.height/4, DefinedValues.height/4));
        else
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams
                    (DefinedValues.width/3-5, DefinedValues.width/3-5));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test3);

    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. What is wrong with the code that you posted?

Comment: I think what you want to ask is basically, you want to update gridview dynamically from the background thread which is downloading images. Am I correct? Because it seems the code above is right. I totally agree with Sam here.

Comment: How do I pass the parent view from adapter class?

Comment: Are you using inflater to populate your UI in adapters getView method?

Comment: No. I updated my question.

Comment: When I get gridView in simple class, all imageViews returned are null